# Strange behavior with log4j2 configuration

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, log4j2

I am working with spring cloud and log4j2 with "all" as level.
I will describe two situations with the same config file, I want to write on a Syslog TCP.

First test: I puth my log4j2 config file in resources folder, then, I start my app and start logging to the syslog.

But I need my configuration on a git, so I expose it to an url.
So here comes the second test:
I changed my bootstrap.yml and and the followind line:

> logging:   config:
>   http://xxx.xx.xx.75:3000/admin123/config-repository/raw/master/log4j2.xml

Then, I started my app and it starts to write the logging lines of spring boot in my syslog, but, when I put:

```
LOGGER.info("printing lalala");
```

Nothing is writed in the syslog and I can see a [FIN, ACK] beetween client and server on my TCP connections.

So, I understand that the config file is readed from the repository, becouse I can see it in my connections capture and becouse the app starts to log on syslog some lines, but something happend after that to close connection and write no more.
I can`t understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the path of the `logging.config` on the `application.yml` not the `bootstrap.yml` and it works.